# imagecreatefromjpeg() returns a black image when resized

Tags: php, image, file, image-processing, file-upload

I have following code

```
 // load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefrompng( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );

  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );


  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = $imageWidth;
  $new_height = 500;

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
```

It works fine with some images..but with certain images it shows an error like

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: 

Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I have also enabled

gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1

in php.ini

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not feature any call to `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [the dreaded "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() : '/tmp/filename' is not a valid JPEG file in /phpfile.php on line xxx"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a blog post from (Feb 2010)](http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/php/imagecreatefromjpeg-gd-jpeg-library-reports-unrecoverable-error/) its a bug in the implementation of `imagecreatefromjpeg` which should return `false` but throws an error instead.

The solution is to check for the filetype of your image (I removed the duplicate call to `imagecreatefromjpeg` because its totally superfluous; we already check for right file type before and if an error occurs due to some other reason, `imagecreatefromjpeg` will return `false` correctly):

```
function imagecreatefromjpeg_if_correct($file_tempname) {
    $file_dimensions = getimagesize($file_tempname);
    $file_type = strtolower($file_dimensions['mime']);

    if ($file_type == 'image/jpeg' || $file_type == 'image/pjpeg'){
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tempname);
        return $im;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can write your code like this:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng_if_correct("{$pathToImages}{$fname}");
if ($img == false) {
    // report some error
} else {
    // enter all your other functions here, because everything is ok
}
```

Of course you can do the same for png, if you want to open a png file (like your code suggests). Actually, usually you will check which filetype your file really has and then call the correct function between the three (jpeg, png, gif).

Answer (score 1):

Please see [PHP Bug #39918 imagecreatefromjpeg doesn't work](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39918). The suggestion is to change the GD setting for jpeg image loading:

```
ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
```

You then additionally need to check the return value from the [`imagecreatefromjpeg`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) call:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
if (!$img) {
    printf("Failed to load jpeg image \"%s\".\n", $file);
    die();
}
```

Also please see the potentially duplicate question:

- [the dreaded “Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() : '/tmp/filename' is not a valid JPEG file in /phpfile.php on line xxx”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3901455/367456)

It has nearly the same error description like yours.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this issue: detect if imagecreatefromjpeg returns 'false' and in that case use imagecreatefromstring on file_get_contents instead.
Worked for me. 
See code sample below:

```
$ind=0;
do{
    if($mime == 'image/jpeg'){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_url_to_upload);
    }elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($image_url_to_upload);
    }
    if ($img===false){
        echo "imagecreatefromjpeg error!\n";
    }
    if ($img===false){
        $img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_url_to_upload));
    }
    if ($img===false){
        echo "imagecreatefromstring error!\n";
    }
    $ind++;
}while($img===false&&$ind<5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give any example of files that do / don't work?
According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#100338 blanks in remote filenamnes might cause issues.

Comment: I've checked for that.But i m not having space in my filename.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using an URL as the source of the image, you will need to make sure the php setting allow_url_fopen is enabled.