# Image is not a valid JPEG

Tags: php, image, loading

I have this code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$size = getimagesize($filename, $info);

var_dump($image);
var_dump($size);
```

And I receive this output:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'my_image.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file

bool(false)

array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(22)
  [1]=>
  int(30)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(22) "width="22" height="30""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

I got warn, that image is not a valid *JPEG* file and don't load that file, but *getimagesize* says that is *JPEG* file (*mime type*). What is happening and how can I fix this?

I tried this, but it didn't help me:

1. check *memory_limit* in *php.ini*
2. check space in the disk
3. set *gd.jpeg_ignore_warning*

Interestingly, on the local server everything works good (with the same image of course).

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file is being found? Try using an absolute path to the image to test (by the error message, it looks like you might be using a relative path) and ensure that your script can find it.

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be possible that `getimagesize()` does not parse all the data (it probably skips some parts) whereas `imagecreatefromjpeg` parses all data.

Comment: Is a correct jpeg image? Could this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe) help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you do: `$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));`

Comment: It return this warning: `imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error`

Comment: But the problem is not affiliated with picture. I noticed that on the local server everything works good (with the same image of course).

Comment: @user3106462 Maybe on your local server you have `gd.jpeg_ignore_warning` enabled?

Comment: @user555 Is disabled (on local server and on remote also).

Comment: @user3106462 What version differences are they between the two servers? What type of color space is the image encoded in?

Comment: @user555 Local: XAMPP with Apache 2.0 and PHP 5.4.19 (working on Mac), remote: Apache 2.2.25 and PHP 5.4.17 (working on Linux). Local server also have this settings (remote not):
`FreeType Support: enabled
FreeType Linkage: with freetype
FreeType Version: 2.4.8 
XPM Support: enabled
libXpm Version: 30411`
Image is RGB, non progressive, non alpha.

Comment: @user3106462 What version of GD and libjpeg are you running on both servers?

Comment: @user555 On both: `GD Version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible), libJPEG Version: 8`

Answer (score 1):

Create Function **isPNG**

```
<?php

function isPNG($file){
    return preg_match('/'.quotemeta('PNG').'/i', file_get_contents($file));
}

?>
```

**Edit your code**

```
<?php

    if(preg_match('/\.(png)$/i', $filename) || isPNG($filename)){
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    }else{
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    }

    $size = getimagesize($filename, $info);

    var_dump($image);
    var_dump($size);
?>
```

Good luck!