# how to fix the magecreatefromjpeg() error in php?

Tags: php

before posting this, I've already tried searching for answers and even bumped into this

[old thread solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe)

but it didn't helped at all. I am very sure that I am passing a .jpg image, but then I am getting this error

```
imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:
```

some say use ini_set("memory_limit", -1) , it didn't help also. I don't think this issue has somethign to do with memory right?, so how to fix this?

Comment: is it a real image ?

Comment: yes it is, it was already in the tmp folder of the server , i even checked and I can open it on preview