# Error Gd Libraries in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, mamp

I Want to use gd Library with symfony but I have this error

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:

My script in my Controller is

```
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
            echo "PHP GD library is enabled in your system.";
        }
        else {
            echo "PHP GD library is not enabled on your system.";
        }

        echo phpinfo();

        $filename = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/logo/logo.png';
        $percent = 0.5;

// Content type
//        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $newwidth = $width * $percent;
        $newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
        imagejpeg($thumb);

        return new Response("foo");
```

In my Phpinfo I can see GD libraries.

I'm using Mamp 3.2.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the dreaded "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() : '/tmp/filename' is not a valid JPEG file in /phpfile.php on line xxx"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with GD library and not related to Symfony. GD is very strict when it comes to the format of JPEG files, as it only accepts a very specific JPEG configuration.

There are many resources on this problem. E.g.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#55402

> If you get this error: "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG
>   library reports unrecoverable error" then check the JPEG files. If
>   they are saved in CMYK format (instead of RGB) then GD will fail to
>   load them (tested with GD 2.0.12)

[the dreaded "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() : '/tmp/filename' is not a valid JPEG file in /phpfile.php on line xxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe)

> It seems that the GD library is less tolerant of buggy JPEG files than
>   other programs. The solution suggested was to set GD to ignore JPEG
>   error's before processing the image, like this:
>
> ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);