# GD fails to create JPG

Tags: php, jpeg, gd

I have an issue with GD not creating a new JPG file, it just fails. No error messages and no indication as to what is happening.  This is not new code, it has been in and working for the past six years, but all of a sudden with larger images it has started failing.

As a background this is running on an old server (to be switched off and moved to a new site on PHP8 in a couple of months time) that has PHP5.3.3 with GD version 2.0.34.

The code is creating thumbnails from the high-res image (around 24-30MB) and outputting a series of thumbnails from 150px wide to 1024px wide. It fails on all.  I have increased the PHP memory limit on the page to 512MB, and set the GD.JPEG_ignore_warning flag for corrupt JPGs.

But every time with these files, this line:

```
$src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
```

just returns FALSE.  But never falls over with an error.  The file is definitely there (run the same code with a file of the same name that is <20MB and it works fine) and there is plenty of disc space/memory available for a 60MB file to be processed in memory, so I dont see that that is the issue.

A search of Google, StackOverflow and several other sites has not produced any similar issues.

Can anyone offer any thoughts as to what the issue/solution is?  I have been looking at this for two days now, and we need to resolve it - simply using smaller JPG files isn't an option for this.

Comment: Do you log your php in the same directory in error_log? if not how about searching your  /etc/httpd/logs/error_log or is in /var/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: remove `@` from function and try again, then report error

Comment: Also, more than most of the time when I encounter errors of this kind... they are because of permissions of the directory ... try to make sure that the php user is allowed to create and save file in the given file path.

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg doesn't create an image it creates a resource

Comment: @Lessmore Oh why didn't I see that. I'd forgotten that @ ignores errors.  With that removed, the code is showing an invalid JPG file, which again is odd as it opens in Apple Quickview, Preview and Adobe Photoshop, and various windows software.

Comment: @Shlomtzion - Thanks I had checked the error_log and nothing in there, and yes all permissions are set right. Like you I have had that before, so it was the first thing I checked!!

Comment: @TIWDEV Looks like you've already found a solution but for an explanation: GD is a pretty minimal library; I strongly suspect what is going on here is that those other pieces of software are better at interpolating or "fixing" a buggy or invalid JPG file. It's analogous to how most modern browsers fix all sorts of invalid HTML, making it invisible to the viewer. You could also try re-saving the file in one of those programs, or, server-side, if you have Imagemagick, run the `convert` or `mogrify` command on it to get it to re-save it and see if that fixes the problem for that file.

Comment: @cazort Yes, I suspect your right. It is purely images that come from one particular camera, ironically a Nikon which I would have expected to save JPGs correctly - all other models do!  The problem here is we dont have Imagemagik on the server, and for a variety of reasons cannot install it.  But thanks for the thought, that would be the better way - to use Imagmagik rather than GD.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Lessmore answer above, GD was reporting an invalid JPG file, so a further search revealed this answer on StackOverflow, which solved the problem by reading the JPG from a string, rather than file:

[Reading an invalid JPG with GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901455/the-dreaded-warning-imagecreatefromjpeg-tmp-filename-is-not-a-valid-jpe)

Thanks all - as ever!